# Not Able to Add Dynamic Variable Into A Dynamic Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at this code and let me know why I am not able add the `variable` into the table?

```js
var variable = "app ha";
var table = '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered"><tr><td>Energy Target</td><td><span class="'+ variable +'"></span></td></tr><tr><td>Run of River Priorities:</td><td><span class="'+ variable +'"></span></td></tr><tr><td>Species:</td><td><span class="'+ variable +'"></span></td></tr><tr><td>Disturbance:</td><td><span class="'+ variable +'"></span></td></tr><tr><td>Slider:</td><td><span class="'+ variable +'"></span></td></tr></table>';

 $("body").append(table);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: There are several empty `<span>` tags, all with the `class="app ha"`, just as would be expected from the above code. What did you think was going to happen instead?

Comment: What do you mean? Your `variable` is being used to set the class of a `span` element as expected.

Comment: Oh my god! I am doing a silly mistake guys! it was suppose to be in span tag not in class sorry for wasting your times!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable is succefully added as `class` attribute, if you want to show it inside `td`s add it also inside column :

```
var table = '<table ....
<tr>
    <td>Energy Target</td>
    <td><span class="'+ variable +'">'+ variable +'</span></td>
</tr>
.....</table>';
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your variable in the span class add it to the inner HTML of the span tags.

```js
    var variable = "app ha";
    var table = '
 <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <tr>
   <td>Energy Target</td>
   <td><span class="">'+variable+'</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Run of River Priorities:</td>
   <td><span class="">'+variable+'</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Species:</td>
   <td><span class="">'+variable+'</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Disturbance:</td>
   <td><span class="">'+variable+'</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Slider:</td>
   <td><span class="">'+variable+'</span></td>
  </tr>
 </table>';

     $("body").append(table);
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```